# How to add images for different screen resolutions in sencha touch?

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can we add images i.e. in android such as small, medium, large and xlarge images in sencha touch as well as for IOS devices for normal display and Retina display? Is there any built in feature or helper function in sencha touch framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with Implementation of `Media Queries` to do so.

Check out below reference links.

[Media Queries to handle all device’s screens](http://chrislee.kr/wp/2012/02/13/media-queries-to-handle-all-devices-screens/)

[HTML5 Media Queries](http://peterkellner.net/2012/02/02/html5-media-queries-tablet-verses-phone-anything-but-intuitive/)

**EDIT :**

If you need to target the Retina display separately, you can use this condition in media queries :

```
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: But how can we use Media queries for ipad/iphone retina display?

Comment: @x4ph4r see the edit in my solution for retina display support.